# How do I dynamically extends the type of a parameter of a function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Code context:

```js
type AnyRecord = Record<any, any>
type handler = <E extends AnyRecord>(record: E) => any

const b = (record: AnyRecord, h: handler) => h(record)

b(
  { a: 3 },
  (record: AnyRecord & { a: number }) => record.a, // Typescript errors (see attached)
)
```

The error:

```
Argument of type '(record: AnyRecord & {    a: number;}) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'handler'.
  Types of parameters 'record' and 'record' are incompatible.ts(2345)
```

How do I dynamically intersect / extends some more interface(s) into AnyRecord to help the IDE with autocompletion?
Thanks in advance!

[image: Typescript errors at line 6]

Comment: please provide the error message in text form not in image read [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Your generics are incorrectly scoped. If you fix it to be [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WkzB9m) it will work. Does that meet your needs If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot @jcalz, the issue is because of the incorrect on line 2, didn't think that `type Handler<E>` and `type Handler = <E>` is different.

Comment: An answer explaining why would be greatly appreciated! @jcalz

Comment: My answer would be very similar to @mandy8055's so I don't think I will bother, unless you think there's something missing in their answer.

Comment: Kk thanks, I have managed to shorten the fix to `handler(record: AnyRecord): any` inside an interface, but just can't wrap my head around how Typescript behaves for all those slightly different cases, if you have some minutes would you interest in explaining [this Playground](https://shorturl.at/F2689)?

Comment: Uh, I mean, I'm not inclined to delve too deeply into stuff if the question is already answered. If you want to open a new question, maybe I'll look at it?  Or if I have time later I'll look here, but I can't commit to it, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256774/discussion-between-dng-quc-trung-and-jcalz).

Comment: Haha just curious to click the platform's recommendation.

Comment: While @mandy8055's answer did fixed the issue it was a overload and not focusing on the culprit, TBH I did not success in applying it to my actual usage as it was a bit different to the post, only clicked when your comment came about the generic's scoping :D. Though, I'm still utterly confused with Typescript's behavior.
If you ever have time for an answer it would definitely be accepted as more fitting and helpful to find my solution, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: BTW Is it possible for me to create a new ELI5 question for the playground explanation?
Not pressuring an answer from you for the playground, just a general question is ELI5 post possible :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your Generics are incorrectly scoped and you'll need to fix this. So the idea here is to basically:

1. Convert the `handler` into a Generic type `Handler<E>`.
2. Update  `b` function to accept a generic type parameter `T` which extends `AnyRecord`.
3. Lastly, change the second argument of the `b` function to accept a `Handler<T>` instead of just a `handler` which will allow `TS` to infer the correct intersection type when calling the `b` function.

```js
type AnyRecord = Record<any, any>
type Handler<E extends AnyRecord> = (record: E) => any

const b = <T extends AnyRecord>(record: T, h: Handler<T>): any => h(record)

b(
  { a: 3 },
  (record: AnyRecord & { a: number }) => record.a
)
```

*[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wy2gAw)*

Comment: Thanks for the help, what was wrong was the incorrect scoping (or could be said incorrect creation of Generic) on line 2.  though in my actual usage the `record` isn't passed in as a param so couldn't enjoy the auto intersection.